# How can we add a milli second to a timestamp field in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I am not aware of any hive function that adds 1 millisecond. For example this is my timestamp value 2018-12-05 10:08:27.950, I want it to be 2018-12-05 10:08:27.951

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward approach to add milliseconds with the inbuilt functions. One approach to do so, albeit ugly is

```
concat(regexp_extract(dt,'(^.{20}'),1),cast(split(dt,'\\.')[1] as int)+1)
```

Extract the first 20 characters of the string and concatenate it with the addition of 1 to the digits following `.` (which is the milliseconds portion).